# What is the real signature of a C++ constructor after compilation

Tags: c++, constructor, hook, reverse-engineering, signature

What is the *real* signature of a constructor in C++?

Background:
I try to hook internal functions of a dll. I have the pdb-Debug Files and were able to get the exact location of the function, including it's undecorated name.
The function looks like:

```
protected: __cdecl ClassName::ClassName(bool * __ptr64) __ptr64
```

So it is obviously a constructor.
I tried void function(void * pThisPointer, bool * pBoolPointer), but as the program crashes after simply forwarding the call (other functions work fine this way), I assume that my signature is wrong.

Do you know what signature to use for a constructor (which is most likely not virtual)?
Or do you have any other ideas what may go wrong?

EDIT:
I use x64 and the visual studio 2010 compiler, the target compiler should be something like the visual studio compiler, as it is a microsoft dll.

Comment: Constructors are not regular functions; there is a lot of magic that goes into them that might or might not be included within the body of whatever method you stumbled upon.

Comment: It is actually __thiscall.  More magic includes calling the base constructor and swapping the vtable pointer at the end.  Stuff you can't easily do yourself.

Comment: I don't need to call it entirely myself. I just want to "wrap" around it. So when you say __thiscall, does that only mean I have to add the void * thisPointer as first argument?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a constructor directly. As far as C++ is concerned, constructors do not have a name. In other words, you cannot call constructors. Many compilers create two or even three *different* functions. Which one should you call?

The answer is none of them. You cannot and must not try to call a constructor directly from your code.

Comment: My pdb file shows a mangled name for the constructor. I see the asm-disassembly of the function. In fact, if I only call it, it works. The program only crashes if I try to increase my debug counter after the call. So my guess is that somehow the stack gets corrupted or something like that. When I increase the counter before the call, everything works fine, too. The compiler should be something similiar to the visual studio compiler

Comment: @ArtificialMind: No, it shouldn't. A constructor obviously must have a name (multiple names, in fact) from the perspective of linking. From the perspective of the language itself, a constructor has no name. What functions, and which functions, are called when you create an instance of some class is not something you should ever depend on. You cannot and must not call a constructor from your code, even by its mangled name. (In fact, directly calling anything by its mangled name is illegal.)

Comment: The dll is a windows dll so it is very unlikely to change in my version. So it should be "safe" to depend on it not changing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to look at the disassembly of the actual constructor and see what it accesses. The usual convention with MSVC (and other compilers) is to pass **`this`** as a hidden first parameter. Usually it's done with **`__thiscall`** convention (i.e. in **`ecx`** on x86), but on x64 there is only one convention, so **`__thiscall`** is the same as **`__cdecl`** or **`__stdcall`**.

However, the other not very well-known convention of MSVC is that *constructors must return the **`this`** pointer*. I suspect that's what's causing your crash.

It's probably not very relevant here, but have a look at [my article](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23) on MSVC C++ internals. It describes x86 implementation, but a lot of things will apply

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't legally take a function pointer to a constructor, it doesn't really have a meaningful signature, as far as C++ itself is concerned.

Implementations do their own thing, but typically a class can have at least two constructor function bodies in the emitted code - one for normal use, and another for when it's used as a virtual base. The compiler knows how to use each one -- you need to know exactly what parts of object construction are done in this emitted code in your implementation, what's done by the caller prior to calling it, what's done by the caller after it returns, and what's done by the caller if it throws an exception, or you can't correctly call it even given that you've figured out its address from debug info.

To reverse-engineer object construction, you should look at the code emitted at a place where an object is created using this constructor.

Comment: Maybe I made myself not clear enough: I don't want to call it myself. I just want to hook it, so I can log when and with what parameter the constructor is called. If i just pass on the parameter I have so far, everything goes fine, I can even increment a global counter variable before calling. But if I try to increment it afterwards, the program crashes. If I log the this-Pointer then I get around 30 different pointers for > 1000 calls, some used more, some used less, but I think that corresponds to the memory management

Comment: @ArtificialMind: I still think your best bet is to look at the code emitted to call it. If you're right, and the stack is corrupted, then perhaps that's because there's some stack manipulation which the caller is required to perform after the constructor returns, but you are not doing before incrementing your counter. That is, the calling convention for this internal constructor function might not be the same as for regular functions, `cdecl` may be misleading. It needn't even be one of the regular calling conventions, although it must be documented somewhere in the Windows C++ ABI.

Comment: that sounds promising. As far as I see, the function starts with `push rbx; sub rsp, 20h` and ends with `add rsp,20h; pop rbx; retn` which I understand as "save rbx, allocate 20byte one stack, deallocate 20 byte on stack, restore rbx, returning" which sounds as I have to ensure that all registers expect rbx (is this the second parameter for calling stack-based conventions?) are the same as entering my function. Is there some intrinsic to save all register and restore them on exit?